# Is there a way for xcb to load a file into a pixmap?

Tags: rust, xcb, pixmap

I'm writing an application with `rust-xcb`. However, when I try to load a file into a pixmap I cannot find any way to do it. I also use `image` library to load image files (jpg).

But I am not familiar with xcb, is there a way for xcb to load pixel buffers or files into pixmap? Or I can find another library to do this?

I have searched for it. Some document of xcb pixmap and bitmap is full of TODO.
I have tried `xcb-util-image`, but didn't find what I need.

My code is below:

```
let foreground = self.connection.generate_id();
    xcb::create_gc(
    &self.connection,
    foreground,
    screen.root(),
    &[
        (xcb::GC_FOREGROUND, screen.white_pixel()),
        (xcb::GC_GRAPHICS_EXPOSURES, 0),
     ],
);
let mut img = image::open(background_src).unwrap();
let img_width = img.width();
let img_height = img.height();

xcb::create_pixmap(
    &self.connection,
    24,
    pixmap,
    self.window_id,
    img_width as u16,
    img_height as u16,
);
let img_buffer = img.to_rgb().into_raw();
xcb::put_image(
    &self.connection,
    xcb::IMAGE_FORMAT_Z_PIXMAP as u8,
    pixmap,
    foreground,
    img_width as u16,
    img_height as u16,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    24,
    &img_buffer,
);
self.flush(); // Flush the connection
```

Comment: One thing that looks wrong about your code: you're not checking your cookies. Tacking `.request_check().unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("{}", e))` onto the end of your calls will help get you an error code if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to the XCB documentation, pixmaps and windows are both drawables: https://xcb.freedesktop.org/colorsandpixmaps/ ("The operations that work the same on a window or a pixmap take an xcb_drawable_t argument")

So, once you've [created](https://docs.rs/xcb/0.8.2/xcb/xproto/fn.create_pixmap.html) your Pixmap, you pass it as the third parameter to [`put_image`](https://docs.rs/xcb/0.8.2/xcb/xproto/fn.put_image.html). No need to worry about converting the Pixmap into a Drawable; they're both just type aliases for `u32` on your end, and they both use the same ID space on the X server's end (as the same docs put it, "a pixmap is basically a window that isn't shown on the screen").

To generate the stuff that goes in the `data` parameter, probably just do the same thing as the [libpng](http://cr.yp.to/2004-494/libpng/libpng-1.2.5/contrib/gregbook/rpng-x.c) source does, but in Rust instead of C.

Comment: Actually, I use `image` library to decode image files and got raw pixel arrays (in rgb format). I have added my code in question description. Could you help me find where the bug is?